# Determining whether $a^x=by+c$ has integer solutions $x,y$ for distinct integer constants $a, b, c$

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

> Is there a way to determine if the following type of equation has an integral solution for both $x$ and $y$?
>
> $$a^x = by +c$$
> where $a, b, c$ are constant integers and $a \neq b \neq c$.

I just want to determine if integral solutions exist does not matter if we can know what actually solutions are.

I tried but cannot figure out. I tried to convert the equation to a linear diophantine by taking log of both sides:

$$x\log(a) = \log(by + c)$$

But I do not think that this could help us much.

Exponential Diophantine equations might help but I have not read much about them.

Comment: Are $a, b, c$ integers?

Comment: @user58697 yes.

Comment: Also for the original question you posted, $x=9+102n$  would do the trick (for whole number values of $n$)

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be restated using modular arithmetic:
$$a^x\equiv c\mod{b}$$
This is known as [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) and is commonly used in cryptography.

As you have correctly guessed, [computing possible values for $x$ is quite difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#:%7E:text=%20on%20the%20other%20hand%2C%20computing%20the%20modular%20discrete%20logarithm%20%E2%80%93%20that%20is%2C%20finding%20the%20exponent%20e%20when%20given%20b%2C%20c%2C%20and%20m%20%E2%80%93%20is%20believed%20to%20be%20difficult.%20this%20one%2Dway%20function%20behavior%20makes%20modular%20exponentiation%20a%20candidate%20for%20use%20in%20cryptographic%20algorithms.) and modular exponentiation is believed to be a [one-way function](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Emlazar/math170/notes06-3.pdf) for most cases.

The values of $c$ often [vary in a cyclic fashion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70658/is-modular-exponentiation-always-cyclical). Finding such a cycle will give a list of values of $c$ for which we can find Diophantine solutions, for given $a$ and $b$. However, the one-way nature of the function makes it computationally inefficient to decide such a cycle for large values of $a$ and $b$. So, in my opinion, deciding whether integer solutions exist may be well out of reach for arbitrary values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

EDIT:

To find such a cycle, the main step is to solve for $x$ in $$a^x\equiv 1 \mod{b}$$ which is computationally difficult as already mentioned. (Further edit: see the [Carmichael function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function))